# Why connected Wifi network has no internet access auto disconnected after few seconds in android?

Tags: android, wifi

I am  programmatically connecting **DashCam camera's WIFI** network which **has no internet access**. Connected successfully, but after few seconds it disconnected automatically. I am developing one DashCam mobile app which has highly recommend this feature.

Connecting scanned result through ConnectorUtils

```
WifiConfiguration config = ConfigSecurities.getWifiConfiguration(wifiManager, scanResult);
if (config != null) {
    ConnectorUtils.connectToConfiguredNetwork(wifiManager, config, true);
} else
    ConnectorUtils.connectToWifi(getApplicationContext(), wifiManager, scanResult, "12345678");
```

ConnectorUtils class

```
public class ConnectorUtils {
    private static final int MAX_PRIORITY = 99999;
    private static final String TAG = ConnectorUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    @Nullable
    private static ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;

    public static boolean isAlreadyConnected(@Nullable WifiManager wifiManager, @Nullable String bssid) {
        if (bssid != null && wifiManager != null) {
            if (wifiManager.getConnectionInfo() != null && wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID() != null &&
                    wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress() != 0 &&
                    Objects.equals(bssid, wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")
    private static boolean checkForExcessOpenNetworkAndSave(@NonNull final ContentResolver resolver, @NonNull final WifiManager wifiMgr) {
        final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
        sortByPriority(configurations);

        boolean modified = false;
        int tempCount = 0;
        final int numOpenNetworksKept = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1
                ? Settings.Secure.getInt(resolver, Settings.Global.WIFI_NUM_OPEN_NETWORKS_KEPT, 10)
                : Settings.Secure.getInt(resolver, Settings.Secure.WIFI_NUM_OPEN_NETWORKS_KEPT, 10);

        for (int i = configurations.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final WifiConfiguration config = configurations.get(i);
            if (Objects.equals(ConfigSecurities.SECURITY_NONE, ConfigSecurities.getSecurity(config))) {
                tempCount++;
                if (tempCount >= numOpenNetworksKept) {
                    modified = true;
                    wifiMgr.removeNetwork(config.networkId);
                }
            }
        }
        return !modified || wifiMgr.saveConfiguration();

    }

    private static int getMaxPriority(@Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager) {
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        int pri = 0;
        for (final WifiConfiguration config : configurations) {
            if (config.priority > pri) {
                pri = config.priority;
            }
        }
        return pri;
    }

    private static int shiftPriorityAndSave(@Nullable final WifiManager wifiMgr) {
        if (wifiMgr == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
        sortByPriority(configurations);
        final int size = configurations.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            final WifiConfiguration config = configurations.get(i);
            config.priority = i;
            wifiMgr.updateNetwork(config);
        }
        wifiMgr.saveConfiguration();
        return size;
    }


    @Nullable
    private static String trimQuotes(@Nullable String str) {
        if (str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
            return str.replaceAll("^\"*", "").replaceAll("\"*$", "");
        }
        return str;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static int getPowerPercentage(int power) {
        int i;
        if (power <= -93) {
            i = 0;
        } else if (-25 <= power && power <= 0) {
            i = 100;
        } else {
            i = 125 + power;
        }
        return i;
    }

    static boolean isHexWepKey(@Nullable String wepKey) {
        final int passwordLen = wepKey == null ? 0 : wepKey.length();
        return (passwordLen == 10 || passwordLen == 26 || passwordLen == 58) && wepKey.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]*");
    }


    private static void sortByPriority(@NonNull final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations) {
        Collections.sort(configurations, (o1, o2) -> o1.priority - o2.priority);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static int frequencyToChannel(int freq) {
        if (2412 <= freq && freq <= 2484) {
            return (freq - 2412) / 5 + 1;
        } else if (5170 <= freq && freq <= 5825) {
            return (freq - 5170) / 5 + 34;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    public static boolean connectToWifi(@NonNull final Context context, @Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager, @NonNull final ScanResult scanResult, @NonNull final String password) {
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (isAndroidQOrLater()) {
            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            return connectAndroidQ(connectivityManager, scanResult, password);
        }

        return connectPreAndroidQ(context, wifiManager, scanResult, password);
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    private static boolean connectPreAndroidQ(@NonNull final Context context, @Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager, @NonNull final ScanResult scanResult, @NonNull final String password) {
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            return false;
        }

        WifiConfiguration config = ConfigSecurities.getWifiConfiguration(wifiManager, scanResult);
        if (config != null && password.isEmpty()) {
//            wifiLog("PASSWORD WAS EMPTY. TRYING TO CONNECT TO EXISTING NETWORK CONFIGURATION");
            return connectToConfiguredNetwork(wifiManager, config, true);
        }

        if (!cleanPreviousConfiguration(wifiManager, config)) {
//            wifiLog("COULDN'T REMOVE PREVIOUS CONFIG, CONNECTING TO EXISTING ONE");
            return connectToConfiguredNetwork(wifiManager, config, true);
        }

        final String security = ConfigSecurities.getSecurity(scanResult);

        if (Objects.equals(ConfigSecurities.SECURITY_NONE, security)) {
            checkForExcessOpenNetworkAndSave(context.getContentResolver(), wifiManager);
        }

        config = new WifiConfiguration();
        config.SSID = convertToQuotedString(scanResult.SSID);
        config.BSSID = scanResult.BSSID;
        ConfigSecurities.setupSecurity(config, security, password);

        int id = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
//        wifiLog("Network ID: " + id);
        if (id == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!wifiManager.saveConfiguration()) {
//            wifiLog("Couldn't save wifi config");
            return false;
        }
        // We have to retrieve the WifiConfiguration after save
        config = ConfigSecurities.getWifiConfiguration(wifiManager, config);
        if (config == null) {
//            wifiLog("Error getting wifi config after save. (config == null)");
            return false;
        }

        return connectToConfiguredNetwork(wifiManager, config, true);
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    public static boolean connectToConfiguredNetwork(@Nullable WifiManager wifiManager, @Nullable WifiConfiguration config, boolean reassociate) {
        if (config == null || wifiManager == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return disableAllButOne(wifiManager, config) && (reassociate ? wifiManager.reassociate() : wifiManager.reconnect());
        }

        // Make it the highest priority.
        int newPri = getMaxPriority(wifiManager) + 1;
        if (newPri > MAX_PRIORITY) {
            newPri = shiftPriorityAndSave(wifiManager);
            config = ConfigSecurities.getWifiConfiguration(wifiManager, config);
            if (config == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Set highest priority to this configured network
        config.priority = newPri;
        int networkId = wifiManager.updateNetwork(config);
        if (networkId == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do not disable others
        if (!wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, false)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!wifiManager.saveConfiguration()) {
            return false;
        }

        // We have to retrieve the WifiConfiguration after save.
        config = ConfigSecurities.getWifiConfiguration(wifiManager, config);
        return config != null && disableAllButOne(wifiManager, config) && (reassociate ? wifiManager.reassociate() : wifiManager.reconnect());
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private static boolean connectAndroidQ(@Nullable ConnectivityManager connectivityManager, @NonNull ScanResult scanResult, @NonNull String password) {
        if (connectivityManager == null) {
            return false;
        }

        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .setSsid(scanResult.SSID)
                .setBssid(MacAddress.fromString(scanResult.BSSID));

        final String security = ConfigSecurities.getSecurity(scanResult);

        ConfigSecurities.setupWifiNetworkSpecifierSecurities(wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder, security, password);


        NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder.build())
                .build();

        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean disableAllButOne(@Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager, @Nullable final WifiConfiguration config) {
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            return false;
        }
        @Nullable final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        if (configurations == null || config == null || configurations.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean result = false;

        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfig : configurations) {
            if (wifiConfig == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (wifiConfig.networkId == config.networkId) {
                result = wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId, true);
            } else {
                wifiManager.disableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId);
            }
        }
//        wifiLog("disableAllButOne " + result);
        return result;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedReturnValue")
    private static boolean disableAllButOne(@Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager, @Nullable final ScanResult scanResult) {
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            return false;
        }
        @Nullable final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        if (configurations == null || scanResult == null || configurations.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean result = false;
        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfig : configurations) {
            if (wifiConfig == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (Objects.equals(scanResult.BSSID, wifiConfig.BSSID) && Objects.equals(scanResult.SSID, trimQuotes(wifiConfig.SSID))) {
                result = wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId, true);
            } else {
                wifiManager.disableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public static boolean enableConfiguredNetworkIfPossible(@Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager, @Nullable final ScanResult scanResult) {
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableConfiguredNetworkIfPossible: WifiManager null");
            return false;
        }
        @Nullable final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        if (configurations == null || scanResult == null || configurations.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableConfiguredNetworkIfPossible: configurations null");
            return false;
        }

        boolean result = false;
        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfig : configurations)
            if (Objects.equals(scanResult.SSID, trimQuotes(wifiConfig.SSID))) {
//                wifiConfig.priority = 40;
//                int netId = wifiManager.updateNetwork(wifiConfig);
                Log.d(TAG, "enableConfiguredNetworkIfPossible: " + wifiConfig.SSID);
                connectToConfiguredNetwork(wifiManager, wifiConfig,false);
//                result = wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId, true);
//                wifiManager.reconnect();
                break;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ScanResult.BSSID:: " + scanResult.BSSID);
                Log.d(TAG, "WifiConfig.BSSID:: " + wifiConfig.BSSID);
                Log.d(TAG, "ScanResult.SSID:: " + scanResult.SSID);
                Log.d(TAG, "WifiConfig.SSID:: " + wifiConfig.SSID);
            }
//        wifiLog("enableConfiguredNetworkIfPossible " + result);
        return result;
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    static boolean cleanPreviousConfiguration(@Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager, @NonNull final ScanResult scanResult) {
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            return false;
        }
        //On Android 6.0 (API level 23) and above if my app did not create the configuration in the first place, it can not remove it either.
        final WifiConfiguration config = ConfigSecurities.getWifiConfiguration(wifiManager, scanResult);
//        wifiLog("Attempting to remove previous network config...");
        if (config == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (wifiManager.removeNetwork(config.networkId)) {
            wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static boolean cleanPreviousConfiguration(@Nullable final WifiManager wifiManager, @Nullable final WifiConfiguration config) {
        //On Android 6.0 (API level 23) and above if my app did not create the configuration in the first place, it can not remove it either.
        if (wifiManager == null) {
            return false;
        }

//        wifiLog("Attempting to remove previous network config...");
        if (config == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (wifiManager.removeNetwork(config.networkId)) {
            wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static void reenableAllHotspots(@Nullable WifiManager wifi) {
        if (wifi == null) {
            return;
        }
        final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        if (configurations != null && !configurations.isEmpty()) {
            for (final WifiConfiguration config : configurations) {
                wifi.enableNetwork(config.networkId, false);
            }
        }
    }
  
    private static boolean isAndroidQOrLater() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q;
    }

    public static String convertToQuotedString(String string) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string))
            return "";

        final int lastPos = string.length() - 1;
        if (lastPos < 0 || (string.charAt(0) == '"' && string.charAt(lastPos) == '"')) {
            return string;
        }

        return "\"" + string + "\"";
    }

    public boolean isWifiEnable(WifiManager wifiManager) {
        return (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() && wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId() != -1);
    }

    public static int getConfiguredNetworkId(WifiManager wifiManager, String ssid) {
        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration config : list) {
            if (config.SSID != null && config.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
                return config.networkId;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

ConfigSecurities class

```
public class ConfigSecurities {
    static final String SECURITY_NONE = "OPEN";
    static final String SECURITY_WEP = "WEP";
    static final String SECURITY_PSK = "PSK";
    static final String SECURITY_EAP = "EAP";


    /**
     * Fill in the security fields of WifiConfiguration config.
     *
     * @param config   The object to fill.
     * @param security If is OPEN, password is ignored.
     * @param password Password of the network if security is not OPEN.
     */

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    static void setupSecurity(@NonNull WifiConfiguration config, String security, @NonNull final String password) {
        config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.clear();
        config.allowedGroupCiphers.clear();
        config.allowedKeyManagement.clear();
        config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.clear();
        config.allowedProtocols.clear();
//        wifiLog("Setting up security " + security);
        switch (security) {
            case SECURITY_NONE:
                config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                break;
            case SECURITY_WEP:
                config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
                config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                // WEP-40, WEP-104, and 256-bit WEP (WEP-232?)
                if (ConnectorUtils.isHexWepKey(password)) {
                    config.wepKeys[0] = password;
                } else {
                    config.wepKeys[0] = ConnectorUtils.convertToQuotedString(password);
                }
                break;
            case SECURITY_PSK:
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                if (password.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]{64}")) {
                    config.preSharedKey = password;
                } else {
                    config.preSharedKey = ConnectorUtils.convertToQuotedString(password);
                }
                break;
            case SECURITY_EAP:
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
                config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X);
                config.preSharedKey = ConnectorUtils.convertToQuotedString(password);
                break;

            default:
//                wifiLog("Invalid security type: " + security);
                break;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    static void setupWifiNetworkSpecifierSecurities(@NonNull WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder, String security, @NonNull final String password) {
//        wifiLog("Setting up WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder " + security);
        switch (security) {
            case SECURITY_NONE:
                // nothing to do
                break;
            case SECURITY_WEP:
                // no longer possible
                break;
            case SECURITY_PSK:
            case SECURITY_EAP:
                wifiNetworkSpecifierBuilder.setWpa2Passphrase(password);
                break;

            default:
//                wifiLog("Invalid security type: " + security);
                break;
        }
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    @Nullable
    static WifiConfiguration getWifiConfiguration(@NonNull final WifiManager wifiMgr, @NonNull final WifiConfiguration configToFind) {
        final String ssid = configToFind.SSID;
        if (ssid == null || ssid.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        final String bssid = configToFind.BSSID != null ? configToFind.BSSID : "";

        final String security = getSecurity(configToFind);


        final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
        if (configurations == null) {
//            wifiLog("NULL configs");
            return null;
        }

        for (final WifiConfiguration config : configurations) {
            if (bssid.equals(config.BSSID) || ssid.equals(config.SSID)) {
                final String configSecurity = getSecurity(config);
                if (Objects.equals(security, configSecurity)) {
                    return config;
                }
            }
        }
//        wifiLog("Couldn't find " + ssid);
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    @Nullable
    static WifiConfiguration getWifiConfiguration(@NonNull final WifiManager wifiManager, @NonNull final String ssid) {
        final List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        final String findSSID = ('"' + ssid + '"');

        for (final WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration : configuredNetworks) {
            if (wifiConfiguration.SSID.equals(findSSID)) {
                return wifiConfiguration;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    @Nullable
    public static WifiConfiguration getWifiConfiguration(@NonNull final WifiManager wifiManager, @NonNull final ScanResult scanResult) {
        if (scanResult.BSSID == null || scanResult.SSID == null || scanResult.SSID.isEmpty() || scanResult.BSSID.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        final String ssid = ConnectorUtils.convertToQuotedString(scanResult.SSID);
        final String bssid = scanResult.BSSID;
        final String security = getSecurity(scanResult);

        final List<WifiConfiguration> configurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        if (configurations == null) {
            return null;
        }

        for (final WifiConfiguration config : configurations) {
            if (bssid.equals(config.BSSID) || ssid.equals(config.SSID)) {
                final String configSecurity = getSecurity(config);
                if (Objects.equals(security, configSecurity)) {
                    return config;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    static String getSecurity(@NonNull WifiConfiguration config) {
        String security = SECURITY_NONE;
        final Collection<String> securities = new ArrayList<>();
        if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE)) {
            // If we never set group ciphers, wpa_supplicant puts all of them.
            // For open, we don't set group ciphers.
            // For WEP, we specifically only set WEP40 and WEP104, so CCMP
            // and TKIP should not be there.
            if (config.wepKeys[0] != null) {
                security = SECURITY_WEP;
            } else {
                security = SECURITY_NONE;
            }
            securities.add(security);
        }
        if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP) ||
                config.allowedKeyManagement.get(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)) {
            security = SECURITY_EAP;
            securities.add(security);
        }
        if (config.allowedKeyManagement.get(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK)) {
            security = SECURITY_PSK;
            securities.add(security);
        }

//        wifiLog("Got Security Via WifiConfiguration " + securities);
        return security;
    }

}
```

Comment: The Wifi disconnect command can be send by any Wifi capable device in the environment (called Wifi deauthentication attack). Some Wifi network providers like companies try to prevent rogue hotspots by this technique. May be the dashcam and your Android phone are both innocent and some of the other networks around you is killing your connection?

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Talk to the Wifi operator, go somewhere where the problematic Wifi is not around or build yourself a faraday cage so the Wifi signals can't get inside. But keep in mind that the deauthentication attack is just one possibility. First you should check if it is really such a deauthentication attack e.g. by opening up a mobile hotspot and try to use it using a different phone.